# Comparing 3 arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, loops

I have the results of 3 queries which I would like to analyze. I've converted them to array to try and avoid burden on the database.

```
allBudgets = Budget.all.to_a
currentBudgets = Budget.select("account_id, amount, year").where("year = '2021'").to_a
actuals = GeneralLedger.all.to_a
```

Lets say allBudgets gets

```
[#<account_id: 1, amount: 50, 2021>,
#<account_id:1, amount: 100, 2020>,
#<account_id:2, amount: 100, 2021>,
#<account_id:2, amount: 150, 2020>,
#<account_id:3, amount: 175, 2020>]
```

currentBudgets would get:

```
[#<account_id: 1, amount: 50, 2021>,
#<account_id:2, amount: 100, 2021>]
```

and actuals gets:

```
[#<account_id: 1, amount: 47, 2021>,
#<account_id:1, amount: 110, 2020>,
#<account_id:2, amount: 99, 2021>,
#<account_id:2, amount: 155, 2020>,
#<account_id:3, amount: 170, 2020>]
```

how can I pull all the accountID from current budget and report on those:

```
[[1, 2020, 100],[1, 2020, 110],[1,2021,50],[1,2021,47],
[2,2020,150],[2,2020,155],[2,2021,100],[2,2021,99]]
```

When I try to use the enumerable iterator, I have been getting the last value repeated over and over.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I could understand from your question, I think you need to use the [pluck](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) method.

```
allBudgets = Budget.all.pluck(:account_id, :amount, :year)
currentBudgets = Budget.where(year: year).pluck(:account_id, :amount, :year)
```

Answer (score 0):

My original code iterated properly.  Was actually getting the last value over and over due to overwriting my variables in a loop.

fwiw pluck works also.